# What does the expression "Sampe examples" mean?

Tags: expressions

Please, help me understand an expression. What does the expression "Sampe examples" mean? "Sample" != "exapmle"?

```
Sampe examples: 
...
code1
...
code2
...
```

Why don't writing just "Example/s"?

```
Examples:
...
code1
...
code2
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's most likely a typo and it should be **Sample examples** which to me is an unnecessary repetition. You're right, the writer could just have written **Example/s**. Where is the text from?

Comment: Thank you! I read it there http://fancybox.net/howto (5th block).

Comment: @WebsF It seems to have been corrected in the text now. Glad to help!